# Empirical distribution function for sample

Tags: self-study, distributions, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I have a short question regarding empirical distribution function.

> We have a sample of $(1, 2.1, 1.5, 3)$. What's the value of the empirical distribution function for this sample $F_{4}$ at $x=2$?

Can you please help me with this one?

My initial solution (exercise number 7) I'm not sure about that. My offers for the answers are either 1 or 1/2.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3iYc.jpg

Comment: Your thoughts...?

Comment: Edited the post @StubbornAtom

Comment: Please use proper math formatting for  your post. Pictures aren't good enough.

Comment: The question asks what proportion of the sample has values less than or equal to $2.$

Comment: @whuber so .. as 1 and 1.5 are the values less (or equal) to 2 and as we have 4 values in the sample, then the proportion is 1/2. And this is the final answer?